# elasticsearch term aggregation over not_analyzed string returns buckets with very low doc count

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-elasticsearch

While playing with AWS Elasticsearch (2.3), I loaded it with some sample data
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/3.0/snippets/shakespeare.json with following mapping

```
$ curl --url "https://my_es_id.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com/shakespeare/_mapping"

{
    "shakespeare": {
        "mappings": {
            "act": {
                "properties": {
                    "line_id": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "line_number": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "play_name": {
                        "fields": {
                            "raw": {
                                "index": "not_analyzed",
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "speaker": {
                        "fields": {
                            "raw": {
                                "index": "not_analyzed",
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "speech_number": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "text_entry": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                }
            },
            "line": {
                "properties": {
                    "line_id": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "line_number": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "play_name": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "speaker": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "speech_number": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "text_entry": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                }
            },
            "scene": {
                "properties": {
                    "line_id": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "line_number": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "play_name": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "speaker": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "speech_number": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "text_entry": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now when I run a query to get speaker counts over the entire data I get the following result.

```
$ curl -XPOST "https://my_es_id.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com/shakespeare/_search" -d'
{
    "aggs" : {
        "speakers" : {
            "terms" : { "field" : "speaker.raw"}
        }
    }
}'

{
    "_shards": {
        "failed": 0,
        "successful": 5,
        "total": 5
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "speakers": {
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "doc_count": 4,
                    "key": "BASTARD"
                },
                {
                    "doc_count": 3,
                    "key": "HAMLET"
                },
                {
                    "doc_count": 3,
                    "key": "KING HENRY VIII"
                },
                {
                    "doc_count": 3,
                    "key": "OF SYRACUSE"
                },
                {
                    "doc_count": 3,
                    "key": "PROSPERO"
                },
                {
                    "doc_count": 3,
                    "key": "WARWICK"
                },
                {
                    "doc_count": 2,
                    "key": "ADRIANO DE ARMADO"
                },
                {
                    "doc_count": 2,
                    "key": "ARCHBISHOP OF YORK"
                },
                {
                    "doc_count": 2,
                    "key": "AUFIDIUS"
                },
                {
                    "doc_count": 2,
                    "key": "BENEDICK"
                }
            ],
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 153
        }
    },
    "hits": {
        "hits": [
            {
                "_id": "0",
                "_index": "shakespeare",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "line_id": 1,
                    "line_number": "",
                    "play_name": "Henry IV",
                    "speaker": "",
                    "speech_number": "",
                    "text_entry": "ACT I"
                },
                "_type": "act"
            },
            {
                "_id": "14",
                "_index": "shakespeare",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "line_id": 15,
                    "line_number": "1.1.12",
                    "play_name": "Henry IV",
                    "speaker": "KING HENRY IV",
                    "speech_number": 1,
                    "text_entry": "Did lately meet in the intestine shock"
                },
                "_type": "line"
            },
            {
                "_id": "19",
                "_index": "shakespeare",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "line_id": 20,
                    "line_number": "1.1.17",
                    "play_name": "Henry IV",
                    "speaker": "KING HENRY IV",
                    "speech_number": 1,
                    "text_entry": "The edge of war, like an ill-sheathed knife,"
                },
                "_type": "line"
            },
            {
                "_id": "22",
                "_index": "shakespeare",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "line_id": 23,
                    "line_number": "1.1.20",
                    "play_name": "Henry IV",
                    "speaker": "KING HENRY IV",
                    "speech_number": 1,
                    "text_entry": "Whose soldier now, under whose blessed cross"
                },
                "_type": "line"
            },
            {
                "_id": "24",
                "_index": "shakespeare",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "line_id": 25,
                    "line_number": "1.1.22",
                    "play_name": "Henry IV",
                    "speaker": "KING HENRY IV",
                    "speech_number": 1,
                    "text_entry": "Forthwith a power of English shall we levy;"
                },
                "_type": "line"
            },
            {
                "_id": "25",
                "_index": "shakespeare",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "line_id": 26,
                    "line_number": "1.1.23",
                    "play_name": "Henry IV",
                    "speaker": "KING HENRY IV",
                    "speech_number": 1,
                    "text_entry": "Whose arms were moulded in their mothers womb"
                },
                "_type": "line"
            },
            {
                "_id": "26",
                "_index": "shakespeare",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "line_id": 27,
                    "line_number": "1.1.24",
                    "play_name": "Henry IV",
                    "speaker": "KING HENRY IV",
                    "speech_number": 1,
                    "text_entry": "To chase these pagans in those holy fields"
                },
                "_type": "line"
            },
            {
                "_id": "29",
                "_index": "shakespeare",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "line_id": 30,
                    "line_number": "1.1.27",
                    "play_name": "Henry IV",
                    "speaker": "KING HENRY IV",
                    "speech_number": 1,
                    "text_entry": "For our advantage on the bitter cross."
                },
                "_type": "line"
            },
            {
                "_id": "40",
                "_index": "shakespeare",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "line_id": 41,
                    "line_number": "1.1.38",
                    "play_name": "Henry IV",
                    "speaker": "WESTMORELAND",
                    "speech_number": 2,
                    "text_entry": "Whose worst was, that the noble Mortimer,"
                },
                "_type": "line"
            },
            {
                "_id": "41",
                "_index": "shakespeare",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "line_id": 42,
                    "line_number": "1.1.39",
                    "play_name": "Henry IV",
                    "speaker": "WESTMORELAND",
                    "speech_number": 2,
                    "text_entry": "Leading the men of Herefordshire to fight"
                },
                "_type": "line"
            }
        ],
        "max_score": 1.0,
        "total": 111396
    },
    "timed_out": false,
    "took": 28
}
```

The document counts in the buckets of aggregation seem abysmally low. What I expected to see is the following speakers with doc counts (the following I calculated by explicitly evaluating the speaker count for the entire data):

```
GLOUCESTER 1920
HAMLET 1582
IAGO 1161
FALSTAFF 1117
KING HENRY V 1086
BRUTUS 1051
OTHELLO 928
MARK ANTONY 927
KING HENRY VI 917
DUKE VINCENTIO 909
```

I have spent several hours searching online the reason for this problem but I can't understand. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause is the bug in mapping and way the data is being searched. Mapping is set for only doc_type:'act' when it should be set for doc_type:'line', also the search shouldn't be over everything instead just doc_type:'line'.

Detailed answer:

Following the example from this page: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/aggregations-and-analysis.html I realized the bug was in the mapping.

Before:

- I didn't realize the original dataset had multiple doc_types.
- In the mapping, only the doc_type:'act' had the field:'speaker' with a not_analyzed version
- I was searching without setting any doc_type
- I was expecting the results would bucket the speakers from doc_type:line when in reality those doc_type didn't have any 'speaker.raw' attribute at all.
- Given this, the count in the question is also wrong.

After:

- The new mapping adds a multifield for field:'speaker' for each of the doc_types: act/scene/line. This is speaker.raw and not analyzed.
- The new search, correctly searches for speakers of the lines, which was the original intent.
- The results from elastic search now match the count I'm manually getting from this dataset. The current count for top 10 speakers in the doc_type:line is as follows:

  GLOUCESTER 1907
  HAMLET 1572
  IAGO 1153
  FALSTAFF 1109
  KING HENRY V 1076
  BRUTUS 1043
  OTHELLO 928
  MARK ANTONY 915
  KING HENRY VI 909
  DUKE VINCENTIO 901

Here is the correct mapping:

```
{
  "shakespeare" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "line" : {
        "properties" : {
          "line_id" : {
            "type" : "integer"
          },
          "line_number" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "play_name" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "fields" : {
              "raw" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "index" : "not_analyzed"
              }
            }
          },
          "speaker" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "fields" : {
              "raw" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "index" : "not_analyzed"
              }
            }
          },
          "speech_number" : {
            "type" : "integer"
          },
          "text_entry" : {
            "type" : "string"
          }
        }
      },
      "act" : {
        "properties" : {
          "line_id" : {
            "type" : "integer"
          },
          "line_number" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "play_name" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "fields" : {
              "raw" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "index" : "not_analyzed"
              }
            }
          },
          "speaker" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "fields" : {
              "raw" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "index" : "not_analyzed"
              }
            }
          },
          "speech_number" : {
            "type" : "integer"
          },
          "text_entry" : {
            "type" : "string"
          }
        }
      },
      "scene" : {
        "properties" : {
          "line_id" : {
            "type" : "integer"
          },
          "line_number" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "play_name" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "fields" : {
              "raw" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "index" : "not_analyzed"
              }
            }
          },
          "speaker" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "fields" : {
              "raw" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "index" : "not_analyzed"
              }
            }
          },
          "speech_number" : {
            "type" : "integer"
          },
          "text_entry" : {
            "type" : "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With the new mapping in place the results look right:

```
curl -XPOST "https://my_es_id/shakespeare/line/_search" -d'
{
    "aggs" : {
        "speakers" : {
            "terms" : { "field" : "speaker.raw"}
        }
    }
}'
{
    "_shards": {
        "failed": 0,
        "successful": 5,
        "total": 5
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "speakers": {
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "doc_count": 1907,
                    "key": "GLOUCESTER"
                },
                {
                    "doc_count": 1572,
                    "key": "HAMLET"
                },
                {
                    "doc_count": 1153,
                    "key": "IAGO"
                },
                {
                    "doc_count": 1109,
                    "key": "FALSTAFF"
                },
                {
                    "doc_count": 1076,
                    "key": "KING HENRY V"
                },
                {
                    "doc_count": 1043,
                    "key": "BRUTUS"
                },
                {
                    "doc_count": 928,
                    "key": "OTHELLO"
                },
                {
                    "doc_count": 915,
                    "key": "MARK ANTONY"
                },
                {
                    "doc_count": 909,
                    "key": "KING HENRY VI"
                },
                {
                    "doc_count": 901,
                    "key": "DUKE VINCENTIO"
                }
            ],
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 461,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 94715
        }
    },
    "hits": {
        "hits": [
            {
                "_id": "14",
                "_index": "shakespeare",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "line_id": 15,
                    "line_number": "1.1.12",
                    "play_name": "Henry IV",
                    "speaker": "KING HENRY IV",
                    "speech_number": 1,
                    "text_entry": "Did lately meet in the intestine shock"
                },
                "_type": "line"
            },
            {
                "_id": "19",
                "_index": "shakespeare",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "line_id": 20,
                    "line_number": "1.1.17",
                    "play_name": "Henry IV",
                    "speaker": "KING HENRY IV",
                    "speech_number": 1,
                    "text_entry": "The edge of war, like an ill-sheathed knife,"
                },
                "_type": "line"
            },
            {
                "_id": "22",
                "_index": "shakespeare",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "line_id": 23,
                    "line_number": "1.1.20",
                    "play_name": "Henry IV",
                    "speaker": "KING HENRY IV",
                    "speech_number": 1,
                    "text_entry": "Whose soldier now, under whose blessed cross"
                },
                "_type": "line"
            },
            {
                "_id": "24",
                "_index": "shakespeare",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "line_id": 25,
                    "line_number": "1.1.22",
                    "play_name": "Henry IV",
                    "speaker": "KING HENRY IV",
                    "speech_number": 1,
                    "text_entry": "Forthwith a power of English shall we levy;"
                },
                "_type": "line"
            },
            {
                "_id": "25",
                "_index": "shakespeare",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "line_id": 26,
                    "line_number": "1.1.23",
                    "play_name": "Henry IV",
                    "speaker": "KING HENRY IV",
                    "speech_number": 1,
                    "text_entry": "Whose arms were moulded in their mothers womb"
                },
                "_type": "line"
            },
            {
                "_id": "26",
                "_index": "shakespeare",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "line_id": 27,
                    "line_number": "1.1.24",
                    "play_name": "Henry IV",
                    "speaker": "KING HENRY IV",
                    "speech_number": 1,
                    "text_entry": "To chase these pagans in those holy fields"
                },
                "_type": "line"
            },
            {
                "_id": "29",
                "_index": "shakespeare",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "line_id": 30,
                    "line_number": "1.1.27",
                    "play_name": "Henry IV",
                    "speaker": "KING HENRY IV",
                    "speech_number": 1,
                    "text_entry": "For our advantage on the bitter cross."
                },
                "_type": "line"
            },
            {
                "_id": "40",
                "_index": "shakespeare",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "line_id": 41,
                    "line_number": "1.1.38",
                    "play_name": "Henry IV",
                    "speaker": "WESTMORELAND",
                    "speech_number": 2,
                    "text_entry": "Whose worst was, that the noble Mortimer,"
                },
                "_type": "line"
            },
            {
                "_id": "41",
                "_index": "shakespeare",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "line_id": 42,
                    "line_number": "1.1.39",
                    "play_name": "Henry IV",
                    "speaker": "WESTMORELAND",
                    "speech_number": 2,
                    "text_entry": "Leading the men of Herefordshire to fight"
                },
                "_type": "line"
            },
            {
                "_id": "44",
                "_index": "shakespeare",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "line_id": 45,
                    "line_number": "1.1.42",
                    "play_name": "Henry IV",
                    "speaker": "WESTMORELAND",
                    "speech_number": 2,
                    "text_entry": "A thousand of his people butchered;"
                },
                "_type": "line"
            }
        ],
        "max_score": 1.0,
        "total": 106228
    },
    "timed_out": false,
    "took": 48
}
```

Comment: Would you mind adding an answer that shows how you addressed it? This will help others who find your question in the future :)